# HTML page to Print - How to manipulate the printer settings prior to printing automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, media-queries, printing-web-page

My client wants their client to be able to print the results of an  html page in a printer friendly format so using media queries and css we created a print stylesheet. When we look at the page in print preview, the printer sets the document up to be at 100%.

Unforunately at 100% printer size the document resizes everything to stretc acrossed and the page breaks but at 50% printer size everything is in tact, also automatically the printer setting are set up to not have it checked to allow images and background images. How can I force it to make it so that when a person clicks print in this specific html page that it forces the page to render at 50% so that it shows everything and that it forces it to show images and background images. So that the page at the end prints the way we want it to print.

Comment: I already tried to change the page width to 50% in the media query that doesn't work it has to pretty much resize the entire document as one. so that it all fits on one page.

Comment: You can try adding `zoom:0.5` in your print query. I am not sure how to handle the image display problem.

Comment: That works to shrink the page but in the print preview console when you click 50% it shrinks the entire website down to 50% so it shows as one page. This is getting close though but it looks as it did at 100% but it's just shrunk down now. I need it to show the entire website in tact but shrinked to print so that the page fits to page.

Comment: it's almost like it stretches everything so that it fits at 100% width then when you click 50% it takes it back to its original format

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using exact page size you want.

```
@media print 
{
   @page
   {
    size: 5.5in 8.5in;
    size: landscape;
  }
}
```